# backgroundColor change JavaScript

Tags: javascript, background-color

I want to target this:

```
<h3 id='month'>Oct</h3>
```

I did this:

```
    var changeColor = function () {
        var monName = new Array ('Jan' ... 'Dec'); //ellipsis to make code short
        var now = new Date();

        if(monName == monName[now.getMonth()]) {
           switch(monName) {
                case 'Jan':
                   document.getElementById('month').style.backgroundColor = '#ff3300';
                   break;
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   .
                case 'Dec':
                   document.getElementById('month').style.backgroundColor = '#c2dd8a';
                   break;
                default:
                   alert('Error');

                }     
        }
};
```

I called the function in the html body element (external js file between script tags properly sourced already):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='time.js'></script>
<body onload='changeColor();'>
```

It didn't seem to work. I'm suspecting there is an error with how I target the h3 element. My overall idea is to change the background color as the month changes for the targeted element. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any javascript error?

Comment: You should learn jquery.

Comment: @AmiramKorach because that's just what we need, more people running around who can copy/paste jQuery code that call themselves web developers.

Comment: @Praveen Only the 'Error' message I placed in the default within my switch statement, which tells me that it's not reading any of my switch cases.

Comment: @AmiramKorach I know huh! ... i wouldn't have this headache. lol .. but i'll give JS a shot. For me, it's the solving of a problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your `if` statement to:

```
if(document.getElementById('month').innerHTML == monName[now.getMonth()])
```

Also, your `switch` statement should be:

```
switch(monName[now.getMonth()])
```

Comment: That didn't work. Let me try putting the document.getElement statement inside a variable and see what happens then. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thanks a bunch! Let me go back and chew this code a bit, see if I can understand this. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I would remove the if test completely.

Comment: Not worth an answer, and it may be that he only wants the month to be highlighted if it is the current month.